# How should I reflectively instantiate a parametrized type using guava TypeToken?

Tags: java, reflection, guava

My class TypeRegisterer allows a client to register parameterized types (with the same parameter as TypeRegisterer) and then instantiate them by using their raw type name.

My current solution works but I have an unchecked cast warning and I'm not sure whether it's safe to ignore. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public class TypeRegisterer<T> {
    private Map<String, TypeToken<? extends Base<T>>> registeredTypes;

    public void registerType(TypeToken<? extends Base<T>> typeToken) {
        registeredTypes.put(typeToken.getRawType().getSimpleName(), typeToken);
    }

    public Base<T> initType(String className, T feature) throws Exception {
        // validation and exception handling removed for brevity
        TypeToken<? extends Base<T>> ruleType = registeredTypes.get(className);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<? extends Base<T>> rawType = (Class<? extends Base<T>>) ruleType .getRawType();

        return rawType.getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you do is a bit dangerous. Assuming you never mistype the class name, assuming there are no two classes with the same simple name extending `Base`, etc., it will work. I'd at least check for such conditions. And probably get rid of the `TypeToken` here, since what you're actually using is `Class` alone. Methods like `initType` always returning "just the right thing" are rarely the right thing.

Comment: The class names are being loaded from a database so I'm not really worried misspellings as I would have the same problem with any other way I use to specify the classes to use. I do have a check for whether the class exists but removed it for brevity, I'll put a comment to that effect.

Comment: I'd be happier just using a Class for registering but I was dissuaded from it by the rawType warning and unchecked cast warning, but looking at it at least it looks more obvious what's going on there so I'll change it - thanks @maaartinus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is OK - parameterized types are compiled with [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure), so the parameter information isn't available at runtime.

At runtime, `Class<Base<T>> == Class<Base<Integer>> == Class<Base<Double>>` etc, so the class object referenced by your `rawType` variable is sufficient to instantiate the class.

Comment: Ah, so I could use Class instead of TypeToken but that would move the casting to the registering method and add a raw type warning, so this is probably better.